# Where can I get my English corrected (online)?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes I have to write my documents in English. I try hard to improve my English, but my English is very bad. So it would be really nice if there would by a place on the internet, where people (or algorithms) correct grammar and spelling.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the Help Center guidelines say resource requests are out of the scope of this site.

Comment: lang-8.com is a good site.

Comment: @CopperKettle thank you very much!

Comment: @AlexC.Johnson - you're welcome! My account is http://lang-8.com/1017887 (0:

Comment: @CopperKettle please post your suggestion on the older question. It would save time, energy and patience if we could simply post a link with suggestions next time another newcomer asks for the same service.